# Integer programming: Step function

Tags: integer-programming

I am not sure how to solve the following question:
Show how the following step function can be represented as a 0-1 expression

$f(x)=b_i$  where  $a_{i-1} \le x \le a_i$ , $i=1,2,...n$

where $b_i>b_{i-1}$ for all i=1,2,...,n

Comment: You need to start and end your latex with (double) dollar signs :
$$f(x)=b_{i} a_{(I-1)} \le x \le a_i , I=1,2,...n$$
$$\text{ where } b_{i}>b_{(i-1)} \text{ for all } I=1,2,...,n$$

Comment: Also, you are mixing lower and upper case "i" rather confusingly.

Comment: Any help, please